# Ionic framework bootstrapped inside div

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ionic framework (angularjs) app that I want to display in a browser window inside a div of a predefined size.

When I bootstrap the app it runs the module and works, but displays fullscreen on the window.

Is it possible to bootstrap an ionic framework (angularjs) module to run within a div that is less than the full size of a window?

Here is code that show div with fixed height and width, but app still bootstrapping fullscreen

```
<body>
<div>another div with content</div>
<div id="app" style="width:300px !important; height:600px !important;">
    <ion-side-menus>
        <ion-side-menu-content>
            <ion-nav-bar>
            </ion-nav-bar>
            <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-side-menu-content>
    </ion-side-menus>
</div>
<script>
    var rootNode = $('#app');
    angular.bootstrap(rootNode, ['myApp']);
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: It depends on the `css`. The scope of `Angularjs` initialization only depends on the element in which you have defined it.

Comment: Yes, but I have defined the div at a fixed width and height using css, and when it bootstraps it overides and goes full screen, not sure if this is because of ionic framework is forcing fullscreen, as opposed to just a normal angularjs page (not including ionic)

Comment: Definitely i can say, some other stylings are overriding your's. Could u please use `!important` for your css.

Comment: The css is inline and I did add !important as is in the code above to see if this worked. The code above is a test app and it has no other content. There are no other style sheets or any other code, unless ionic framework itself is overriding the div dimensions itself?